# What's the difference between the "multilingual" and "language" tags?

Tags: discussion

There are two tags, [multilingual](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multilingual) and [language](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language). Multilingual seems easy to understand: It is for sites that have more than one language and are negotiating the complexities involved in that arrangement.

However, [language](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) has no tag wiki and looking at the questions it looks like most of them could be considered [multilingual](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multilingual) and in fact many of them already are. Is there a reason for a separate tag to exist?

Comment: There are then [tag:translation], and [tag:locale].

Answer (score 3):

Since [language](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) is now declared to be a synonym of  [multilingual](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multilingual) (see screen dump below), I assume that this has been resolved and there isn't *supposed* to be a difference.  Fine!

[image: screen dump]

However, this is only a start.  IMHO, the "language"-related tags in the tag wiki needs to be re-thought.  In addition to [language](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) and [multilingual](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multilingual), there are [translation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation), [localization](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/localization), [internationalization](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internationalization), [i18n](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/i18n) and [locale](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/locale).

The last two are supposed to be about two specific modules.  The [i18n](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/i18n) tag is used correctly (most of the time). However, few of the questions tagged [locale](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/locale) is about the (core) [locale](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/locale) module.  Many users use this tag for questions about PHP `setlocale()` - or for general questions about localization and internationalization.

As for the other language-related tags, they seem to be applied more or less interchangeably.

The current tag description of [localization](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/localization), says that localization is:

> usually related to translating content

I find this description unfortunate, because it differs from the industry's standard definition.  Localization is about catering for regional differences and regional technical requirements (e.g. currency, units for weights and measures, character set, timezone, *and* translation).  Maybe some bold editor can change the description into something that makes it less a synonym of "translation"?

Usually "localization" and "internationalization" are regarded synonyms.  Not so here, where [internationalization](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internationalization) (no description) seems to be used as yet another synonym for [multilingual](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multilingual).

I suggest [internationalization](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internationalization) is made a synonym of [localization](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/localization), and that the tag description of [localization](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/localization) is improved.

(Some may argue that these are *not* synononyms.  However, I do not think ordinary users know enough about this to be able to distinguish between these two closely related and overlapping terms.)

Then, keep [i18n](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/i18n) and [locale](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/locale) - but try to *enforce* that they should only be used for questions about the respective modules.

That leaves [translation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation).  Like  [language](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) I think it just should become a synonym of  [multilingual](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multilingual).

Comment: Tags can't be removed as such; they can be blacklisted, but that only happens in extreme circumstances (more extreme than this situation). If a tag exists with no associated questions, it will be automatically removed as part of a daily script, but there's nothing to stop it coming back in a subsequent question (or indeed if it's added to an existing question). Re-tagging is usually the solution to this sort of issue if people feel strongly enough to carry out the work. Since this is about different tags than the OP it might be worth opening a new meta question to discuss it

Comment: Thank's for the insight into the inner workings of SE.  I've edited my answer to *not* have removal of existing tags an option.

Comment: @Clive, apparently, tags can be removed.  I recently did a foolhardy attempt to curate the [tag:Notice] tag (it was without an excerpt, but I checked all instances and its usage was consistent and simple to describe).  It took about 30 minutes before my edit was rejected and the tag was removed (by a diamond mod). To me, it looks like curated tags is depreciated at Drupal.SE.

Answer (score 0):

There are questions about the language that are not about a multilingual site, such as [How do I get the $language object inside a form builder?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24924/d7-how-to-get-language-object-inside-hook-form) and [Best practice for language key for "und" in hook_form_alter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25839/best-practice-for-drupal-7-language-key-for-und-in-hook-form-alter); vice versa, a question about a multilingual site is about the language.

The options I see are:

- Remove [language](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) from questions that are not about multilingual sites (such as the two questions I reported as example), and merge [language](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) with [multilingual](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multilingual), keeping it for questions about sites where at least a language other than the default one is enabled.
- keep [language](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language), and make [multilingual](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multilingual) its synonym.

Keeping [multilingual](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multilingual) would make more evident the question is about a multilingual configuration.

Comment: I would suggest keep locale and mark all others as synonym.